# WinAPI CredEnumerate returning only Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm working on a browser and I'm using Credentials Store to save passwords.

My problem is that the `CredEnumerate` function returns only Windows Credentials but I actually need Web Credentials. I'm using this class:  https://gist.github.com/meziantou/10311113.

Do I need to pass a different parameter to the `CredEnumerate` function to return Web Credentials? I couldn't see any information about this on MSDN.

Comment: What do you mean by "web credentials"? It depends on the browser, not the OS.

Comment: Nope. You can check it yoursef. Go to control panel > user accounts > credentials. There is 2 tab here. One is Wİndows Credentials and the other is Web.

Comment: This has nothing to do with browsers credentials, if that's what you're after

Comment: Yes, I want to import saved passwords from different browsers. There are lots of password recovery tools out there so I'm sure there is something to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the `CredEnumerate` function, set the second flag parameter to 1.

Look into the below documentation link for `CRED_ENUMERATE_ALL_CREDENTIALS`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374794(v=vs.85).aspx

So try by passing 1 for second parameter instead of zero.

```
bool ret = CredEnumerate(null, 1, out count, out pCredentials);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

What Operating System are you targeting? For IE, from Windows 8 onward, I suggest you look at `Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault` `RetrieveAll()` and `RetrievePassword()`.

In any case, the bottom line is that it really depends on the browser... I think this article will help you greatly: http://raidersec.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html (and the links in the article too ie. http://securityxploded.com/iepasswordsecrets.php)

Comment: As i know  `Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault` namespace supported since .Net 4.5. This is big dependency issue.

Comment: In addition, in your referenced article they are using `CredEnumerate` function to retrieve credentials but same concept not working for me.